# generate serial No with arrayformula relative to previous column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

i'm trying to get dynamic serial number for my accounts tree excluding blanks and relative to the previous column but i couldn't mange to achieve that with arrayformula
[copy of my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y_Zfwos5KDbY8EbHY2euUd6HjYOmpOm0g3QF_e5Eqj4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

start with:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A, A2:A<>"")), SEQUENCE(COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your help i really appreciate it , but it only works for level 1